# The use of let in the divisors function

Tags: scheme, racket

```
    (define divisors       
      (lambda (n)
        (let f ((i 2))
          (cond  ((>= i n) '())
                ((integer? (/ n i))  (cons i (f (+ i 1))))
                (else (f (+ i 1)))))))
```

I'm a little confused with the `(let f ((i 2)).....)` part as well as the recursive calls using `(f (+ i 1))`.

Does `f` become all `((i 2))`? and how does the `(f (+ i 1))` part work exactly? I figure `(+ i 1)` becomes `3`, but then what happens?

*edit:* I am not quite sure how the `let` works. I'm not quite sure how to phrase what I don't understand. If someone could explain how the `let` works in general with that recursive call, that would be helpful. I've seen other examples of `let`, but I don't understand really how it works in this method.

*edit2:* Thank you, I did not know it was called a *named* *`let`*. I was looking up `let` and I found `let*` but they did not go over named `let`.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. We are happy to help here, but can you please edit your queston and format your code properly? As it is now - it's unreadable :(

Comment: This construction is called a "named let". I don't have time at the moment to elaborate, but that should help you be able to stretch for more about it.

Comment: See, e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31909121/how-does-the-named-let-in-the-form-of-a-loop-work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the named let in the form of a loop work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31909121/how-does-the-named-let-in-the-form-of-a-loop-work)

Answer (score 3):

A symbol as the first part of a`let` is called a named `let`. You might know that a standard `let`:

```
(let ((i 2))
  body ...)
```

Is just an abbreviation for an anonymous function that is called right away:

```
((lambda (i)
   body ...)
 2)
```

With the named `let` you give that function a name so you can call it as a function from withing the body. With the exception that there is less shadowing it is the equivalent of this:

```
(define (divisors n)
  (define (f i)
    (cond  ((>= i n) '())
          ((integer? (/ n i))      (cons i (f (+ i 1))))
          (else (f (+ i 1)))))
  (f 2))
```

So to answer your question the initial `i` is `2`. Then the recursive call increases `i` to `3` and so on in the same manner as the above code does. As with all calls the bound variables are local to the call so each and every round has their own `i`.

Now if you look at this and the version with the named `let` you will notice that the arguments and the bindings are closer together in a `let` and thus the intent of the code is easier to understand. Also when you know that a named `let` lets you call the same block with new bindings you will think the named `let` is easier to read than the alternative.

Comment: Quick question on how the `i` becomes `3`? In the named let version, you pass `f 3` to `f (i 2)`  wouldn't it become `f (3 2)` and then `3` would become `2`?

Comment: @cicero866 `(let f ((i 2)) ...)` means the function `f` is first called with first argument `i` being value `2`. When you call `(f 3)` then `f` is called with `i` as `3`. You need to read my answer again and pay attention to the fact that my equivalent code is exactly the same thing happening as with the named `let`.

Comment: @WillNess But it's kind of a function call if you compare it to the `define` + apply equivalent. I've tried to keep away from saying goto since each call to `f` returns and sometimes back to the calling `f` which is not very goto-y.

Comment: @Sylwester ah, yes, it wasn't *very* precise of me, to say the least... he he. the `((i 2))` though still is very much *not* the function call (just so that's clear to the OP). BTW have you ever seen / wrote the `(loop ... (loop ...))` kind of code with the named let? where would it fit, some kind of tree traversal perhaps?

Comment: @WillNess [Tree traversal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40443912/1565698) fits, but you wouldn't use the name `loop` since it hints towards tail recursion and at best only one of the followed branches would be tail calls.